# Right Approach to Deploy Two Django App in Apache httpd server?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Two Django Application which is created using `python 3.8.x` and python `3.9.x` version.

Now I need to deploy both apps in apache server in the same system in windows machine.

and iam using `mod_wsgi version 4.8.0`

I Tried some things like settings two different instance of apache as well as listening to two different ports in single apache server

and the error iam getting is

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Apache\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Apache\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\Goku\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\Goku\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\Apache\\bin',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run to django apps in ONE Apache Server under Windows you need to define the 2 apps as virtual hosts in httpd-vhosts.conf

But you can NOT define a different environment for the 2 apps as WSGIPythonHome can only be set on httpd.conf for all virtual hosts (unfortunately)

But you could start 2 apache instances with 2 different httpd.conf an change the port at the "listen" instruction. You also need to care about SSL port 443 which is included from httpd-ssl.conf.

The Error message you posted has nothing to do with ports etc. how does your django related definitions look like in httpd.conf? Also please start httpd from comand line to debug as e.g. XAMPP does not show error messages at Apache startup but just fails.

Comment: I'm Not using XAMPP I'm using Apache Lounge..

for two Instances to run I need to have two Different PythonHome and PythonPath in the environment variables right?